# Saving Point to a Google Fitness API (fitness.body.write)

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Im trying to save a Point with float value into `fitness.body`. 
Getting value is not a problem, while saving a new point causes `403. No permission to modify data for this source.`

Im using DataSetId `derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight` to find point and read value, and `raw:com.google.weight:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input` to insert data.

.

Here is a workflow using Ruby and `google-api-ruby-client`:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
require 'pry'

# Initialize the client.
client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'Example Ruby application',
  :application_version => '1.0.0'
)

fitness = client.discovered_api('fitness')

# Load client secrets from your client_secrets.json.
client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load

flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
  :client_id => client_secrets.client_id,
  :client_secret => client_secrets.client_secret,
  :scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.write']
)
client.authorization = flow.authorize
```

Forming my new data Point:

```
dataSourceId = 'raw:com.google.weight:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input'

startTime = (Time.now-1).to_i # 1 Second ago
endTime = (Time.now).to_i

metadata = {
  dataSourceId: dataSourceId,
  maxEndTimeNs: "#{startTime}000000000", # Faking nanoseconds with tailing zeros
  minStartTimeNs: "#{endTime}000000000",
  point: [
    {
      endTimeNanos: "#{endTime}000000000",
      startTimeNanos: "#{startTime}000000000",
      value: [
        { fpVal: 80 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Attempting to save the point:

```
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => fitness.users.data_sources.datasets.patch,
  :body_object => metadata,
  :parameters => {
    'userId' => "me",
    'dataSourceId' => dataSourceId,
    'datasetId' => "#{Time.now.to_i-1}000000000-#{(Time.now).to_i}000000000"
  }
)
```

And as I indicated previously im getting `403. No permission to modify data for this source`

```
#<Google::APIClient::Schema::Fitness::V1::Dataset:0x3fe78c258f60 DATA:{"error"=>{"er
rors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"forbidden", "message"=>"No permission to modif
y data for this source."}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"No permission to modify data for
this source."}}>
```

I believe, I selected all required permissions in the scope. I tried submitting the point to both accessible datasetid's for fitness.body.

Please let me know if im doing anything wrong here.

Thank you!

Comment: in `userId`, is me authenticated? Are you sending the authentication token in the header?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same situation, turns out you can NOT insert data points directly into the datasource "raw:com.google.weight:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input". From the name, one might guess out this datasource is reserved. So the workaround is to add your own datasource, note should with dataType.name="com.google.weight", like this:

```
{
  "dataStreamName": "xxxx.body.weight", 
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "weight", 
        "format": "floatPoint"
      }
    ], 
    "name": "com.google.weight"
  }, 
  "dataQualityStandard": [], 
  "application": {
    "version": "1", 
    "name": "Foo Example App", 
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com"
  }, 
  "device": {
    "model": "xxxmodel", 
    "version": "1", 
    "type": "scale", 
    "uid": "xxx@yyy", 
    "manufacturer": "xxxxManufacturer"
  }, 
  "type": "derived"
}
```

then after the successful creation, you can use this datasource(datastream id) to insert your own data points, and then the inserted data points will also be included in the datasource "derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight" when you do the querying with suffix "dataPointChanges".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an Authorization header:

```
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => fitness.users.data_sources.datasets.patch,
  :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Bearer YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'},
  :body_object => metadata,
  :parameters => {
    'userId' => "me",
    'dataSourceId' => dataSourceId,
    'datasetId' => "#{Time.now.to_i-1}000000000-#{(Time.now).to_i}000000000"
  }
)
```